# Can I be refunded excess social security tax if my total salary for the year between two jobs exceeds limit?

Tags: united-states, taxes, social-security

For 2020, I will have my income split between company A and company B. Between the two jobs, my income will exceed the limit of $137,700, but it will not exceed it for either specific job.

With that said, I am curious if I can be refunded the overage when I file my taxes in 2021?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  According to the Social Security Administration, you can request a refund of the excess withholding in that case.  [SSA Benefits Planner](https://www.ssa.gov/planners/maxtax.html)

[Topic #608](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc608) at the IRS site gives information about this and directs you to use Form 843.  Specific instructions are covered in [IRS Publication 505](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p505#en_US_2019_publink100015706). The credit is claimed on form 1040 line 72.  (Note that the 2020 versions aren't published yet.)

Comment: For the 2018 Form 1040, it is on Schedule 5 line 72. For the 2019 Form 1040, it is on Schedule 3 line 11.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this will be calculated when you do your 2020 taxes and the amount applied to the tax due.  If the tax paid exceeds the amount due, then you will receive a refund.